# How many monitors can I use with a HP Laptop using a Thunderbolt 2G

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hp

Can I utilize 4 monitors with my HP Elitebook laptop with an Intel UHD 620 graphics card if I have it connected to a Thunderbolt 2 dock? The Thunderbolt 2 will support 4 monitors, but my graphics card typically only supports 3.

Comment: Follow up question. If I can still only use 3 monitors with this setup, would a USB3 to displayport adapter allow me to add a 4th?

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a question in a comment that cannot be answered.

Comment: As the question was a comment, my answer will be one too: Most USB-C display adapters just use one of the graphics card's supported displays (sometimes the only way to get the 3rd display is over USB-C). If it is not USB-C, but USB 3.0 type A then the adapter might actually work for a 4th display. It won't be very good though because the adapter is essentially a GPU over USB and you're not going to get good performance out of a GPU chip like that.

Comment: You wanna use the dock, the card or both of them?